# Applying LINQ's OrderBy method to Users property of UserManager class of ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

In an ASP.NET Core 1.1 app with `Individual User Accounts` authentication, I'm trying to display a `dropdown` of `Users` in an ascending order. But the `VS2015`'s `Intellisense` does not recognize the `.OrderBy(u => u.Value)` of the code below. Why is that?. I then end up using OrderBy on the `.Select(u => new SelectListItem { Value = u.UserName, Text = u.UserName }) that, as expected, works. [Ref: [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151669(v=vs.108).aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager%602.Users) class]

```
public IActionResult GetUserList()
{
    var UserListVM = new UsetListViewModel()
    {
        UserList = _userManager.Users.OrderBy(u => u.Value).Select(u => new SelectListItem { Value = u.UserName, Text = u.UserName }).ToList()
    };
    return View(UserListVM);
}
```

Comment: The linked article is about ASP.NET Identity 2.x, not about ASP.NET Core Identity. Also do you import `System.Linq`?

Comment: @Tseng Yes, `using System.Linq;` is imported by default. Also, in the same controller, I can use `Orderby` on custom tables, e.g.: `_context.myTable.OrderBy(t =>t.ColName)....`